# Noobs minimum/maximum partition size

Tags: raspbian, noobs, openelec, multiboot

I have installed libreelec and raspbian on single SD card using NOOBS. Raspbian got 8GB partition and LibreElec about 5GB. OpenElec takes only 256MB so I would like it to be assigned partition no bigger than 1GB and I would like raspbian to fill rest of the space. How can I achive this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done for Raspbian. I had to download Noobs (not lite) with Raspbian included and change value partition_size_nominal in partitions.json. This value is in fact minimal partition size that will be allocated for Raspbian. It is minimal because partition can be extended by installer.

Answer (score 0):

Changing partition sizes on multi-boot systems is risky, but if you must, use a partition editor from your desktop or laptop. I personally favour GParted on Ubuntu.

Another alternative is to wipe the SD card completely and reinstall by specifying the new partition sizes you want, or making the partitions on the SD card ahead of time, again using a partition editor. For this application, I favour fdisk, available on a number of platforms.

Comment: I wish to tell noobs partirion aize before innstalling

Comment: I've never used noobs, but you can format your SD card in your PC or laptop and make partitions there, and just tell noobs to use those.

Comment: Read this? https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/installation/noobs.md

Comment: You can try Berry Boot --> http://www.howtogeek.com/141325/how-to-multi-boot-your-raspberry-pi-with-berryboot/ , or you can stick with NOOBS and edit the JSON files --> https://github.com/raspberrypi/noobs/wiki/NOOBS-partitioning-explained

Comment: Altering my previous comment per the very helpful link by @tlhlngan I tried the base install you asked about, I didn't see anything obvious as the js files didn't list anything more than default scheme. After reading the link above, the root image has nothing to do with partitioning as I once thought. So may have to experiment with writing your own schemes and not setting 'want_maximised: true' for a specific partion that you want a set size for.